# How to remove all entries of a specific ID after a binary variable becomes true in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have the following *already sorted* dataset:

```
ID Dead
01    F
01    F
01    T
01    T
01    T
02    F 
02    F
02    F
02    F
02    T
03    T
03    T
03    T
03    T
03    T
```

We have 3 IDs (01, 02, and 03) and whether the individual is dead (True or False). I want the indices where the individuals are alive and the initial row when the individual died, which would leave me with the following dataset:

```
    ID Dead
 0  01    F
 1  01    F
 2  01    T
 5  02    F 
 6  02    F
 7  02    F
 8  02    F
 9  02    T
10  03    T
```

I came up with a solution that involves looping over all rows and appending the ID to a list if they have died previously. Is there a quicker approach?

Edit:
It also has to be in order. Data is not "perfect", for example, we might have the following dataset:

```
ID Dead
04    F
04    T
04    F
04    F
04    F
```

And the desired output is:

```
ID Dead
04    F
04    T
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want "Dead" equal "F" OR not duplicated on "ID+Dead"

You can use boolean indexing:

```
m1 = df['Dead'].eq('F')
m2 = ~df.duplicated(['ID', 'Dead'])

df[m1|m2]  # keep if either mask is True
```

output:

```
    ID Dead
0    1    F
1    1    F
2    1    T
5    2    F
6    2    F
7    2    F
8    2    F
9    2    T
10   3    T
```

##### updated example: stop after the first T

```
# dead
m = df['Dead'].eq('T')
# fill incorrect Alive after Dead and compute mask
mask = m.where(m).groupby(df['ID']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift())
df[~mask.fillna(False)]
```

output:

```
    ID Dead
0    1    F
1    1    F
2    1    T
5    2    F
6    2    F
7    2    F
8    2    F
9    2    T
10   3    T
15   4    F
16   4    T
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. What if the order was different. Please see edit.

Comment: @user572780 this should be the case, if not please provide a counter example

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: @user572780 I see, then sort your data first: `df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Dead'])` conveniently F sorts before T (also valid with booleans False/True)

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear. The data is already sorted. For example, if we had a hospital that keeps punching in F unless there is paperwork that the individual has died.  So for t=1, False, for t=2, there is paperwork -> True, for 3=3, there is no paperwork -> False. And now we want the data up to the point where the individual died.

Comment: @user572780 got it! see update

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `groupby` with `transform` `idxmax`

```
out = df[df.index<=df['Dead'].eq('T').groupby(df['ID']).transform('idxmax')]
Out[545]: 
    ID Dead
0    1    F
1    1    F
2    1    T
5    2    F
6    2    F
7    2    F
8    2    F
9    2    T
10   3    T
```

Or

```
out = df[df['Dead'].eq('T').groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()<=1]
Out[546]: 
    ID Dead
0    1    F
1    1    F
2    1    T
5    2    F
6    2    F
7    2    F
8    2    F
9    2    T
10   3    T
```

---

For update example

```
out = df[df.index<=df['Dead'].eq('T').groupby(df['ID']).transform('idxmax')]
out
Out[552]: 
    ID Dead
0    1    F
1    1    F
2    1    T
5    2    F
6    2    F
7    2    F
8    2    F
9    2    T
10   3    T
15   4    F
16   4    T
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does the first example work with ID=04? Please see edit of ID=4.

Comment: @user572780 1st example work for that , you can check

Comment: @user572780 also you can check the update

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), a pandas wrapper that reimagines pandas APIs:

##### Construct data

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, f, rep, tibble, group_by, filter, cumsum
[2022-03-31 11:03:49][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "filter" has been overriden by datar.
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     ID=rep(["01", "02", "03", "04"], each=5),
...     Dead=c(
...         rep(["F", "T"], [2, 3]),
...         rep(["F", "T"], [4, 1]),
...         rep(["F", "T"], [0, 5]),
...         rep(["F", "T", "F"], [1, 1, 3]),
...     )
... )
>>> df
         ID     Dead
   <object> <object>
0        01        F
1        01        F
2        01        T
3        01        T
4        01        T
5        02        F
6        02        F
7        02        F
8        02        F
9        02        T
10       03        T
11       03        T
12       03        T
13       03        T
14       03        T
15       04        F
16       04        T
17       04        F
18       04        F
19       04        F
```

##### Filter data

```py
>>> df >> group_by(f.ID) >> filter(cumsum(cumsum(f.Dead=="T")) <= 1) 
         ID     Dead
   <object> <object>
0        01        F
1        01        F
2        01        T
3        02        F
4        02        F
5        02        F
6        02        F
7        02        T
8        03        T
9        04        F
10       04        T
[TibbleGrouped: ID (n=4)]
```

##### Explain

The first `cumsum()` makes sure the earlier appeared `F`s are marked `0`. The second makes sure the `F`s after `T`s are marked as values > 1.